# How to change the window color (default: white)?

Tags: 11.10, gedit, themes, colors

1. How to change the **window color** (default: white) in Oneiric? (In Natty, I could do it in `Appearance`.)
2. (If 1 doesn't work) How to change the background color in **Gedit**? (In Natty, by right clicking I could find `profile` or something like that.)

Comment: The window theme you mean?

Comment: No, just color I meant, as I could in Natty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tweakability of Oneiric has suffered due to the switch to *gnome 3*, so for #2:

gedit supports the themes available in package *libgtksourceview2.0-common*, and if you are willing to, you can create your own or download a large selection from the net.

Click on Edit/Preferences, on the preferences dialog switch to *Fonts & Themes* and pick a theme.