# How do I change the default application window background?

Tags: 11.10, customization

I still can't find a way of changing the default white color of applications window backgrounds. It does hurt my eyes and I used to adjust it so easily up to 10.04.

There was this post: [How to change the background colour of a window?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68003/how-to-change-the-background-colour-of-a-window), explaining how to tweak some things, but they don't affect the white background.

Also another sufferer tried to ask the question [How to change the window color (default: white)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/63488/how-to-change-the-window-color-default-white) but it was closed!
Please help.

Answer (score 2):

The problem you are facing is due to the change to gnome (and gtk) 3 , so there are not yet as many themes available.

For advice on how to manually customize your theme See [How do I make a Theme from scratch for Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47643/how-do-i-make-a-theme-from-scratch-for-unity)

You can try themes from

Over time more an more people will likely contribute themes to gnome.look

http://gnome-look.org/index.php?xcontentmode=167

Sometimes the themes (from gnome look) work and sometimes they do not (I do not play with them much)